# JsonArrayRequest not working onResponse method in Android Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Hello friends I have following JSON Array response from a web service and I want to read all the data row wise from the Database and display on Android Activity.

```
[{"id":"2","type":"0","title":"Recruitment at ADANI Port, Mundra","date":"2016-07-01"},{"id":"1","type":"1","title":"Training at DAICT, Gandhinager","date":"2016-07-04"}]
```

I have implemented following code in onCreate() of an Activity using Volley Library, which doesn't show output and to my knowledge it doesn't call onResponse() method.

```
    public void getNews(){
    String url = "http://www.ABCDXYZ.net/tponews.php?tponews=1";
    Log.e("URL",url);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


    JsonArrayRequest jor = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("Resposne", "We have got the response");
                        JSONObject val = response.getJSONObject(0);
                    }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley",error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jor);
}
```

The output is only URL in Log.e("URL",url);  // URL: www.ABCXYZ.net/tponews.php?tponews=1

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions? Does it not log neither the "Response" nor "Volley" and the error?

Comment: Your output does not reflect what you are logging on the Error Listener.  Can you post other codes related to this that you are doing?  Is it crashing?

Comment: Please post your log error for better analysis.